# Cohomology ring of classifying space

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I am looking for $H^*(BZ/2p , Z/2p)$ where $p$ is odd prime.We can calculate cohomology groups by using gysin exact sequence and universal coefficient theorem.But I am unable to calculate the ring structure.looking for help.
Thanking you.

Comment: Have you tried using a spectral sequence?

Comment: @JHF: You mean using the serre fibration $K(Z,1)  \rightarrow K(Z,1)  \rightarrow K(Z/2p ,1)$,where first map is multiplication by 2p.

Comment: @JHF :It is easy to see that $H^{2i}(BZ/2p , Z/2p) =Z/2p\lbrace  t^i \rbrace$ where $t$ belongs to $H^2(BZ/2p,Z/2p)$.By SSS we guarantee that there is class $s$ belongs to $H^1(BZ/2p , Z/2p)$ and $s^2$= 0 because otherwise it will survive at $\infty$-page and that contradict to cohomology of $K(Z,1)$.Is it right?

Comment: You may be right, but how did you differentiate between the cases $s^2 = 0$ and $s^2 = t$ (or some other multiple of $t$)?

Comment: @JHF:You are right. Can u settle it for me?Can you tell me the explicit ring structure?

Comment: Hmm... I don't see a way to figure it out directly from the spectral sequence.  However, we do have an explicit model of $B\mathbb{Z}/2p$ - the infinite lens space.   Working with the 2-skeleton, one can show that $s^2$ is the unique element of order 2 in $H^2(\mathbb{Z}/2p;\mathbb{Z}/2p)$.   See example 3.41 and 3.9 in Hatcher.